# Is it legal to run multiple version of Mac OS X VM on Apple hardware?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

It's often to deploy multi Mac OS X when developing OS X application. It could be easy if you have lots of memory to buy amount of Mac mini (like some picture shows rack of Mac minis). However, if the budget is limited, we can use visualization to run OS X VM on Apple hardware.

From Googling, it should be legal to install 2 guest OS X (10.7-10.11) VM on an apple made hardware. And there are my questions.

1. Can any one share some experience about above scenario? You do buy lots of Mac mini and management directly or you install VMware ESXi on Mac mini and OS X Mvs.
2. As title, in testing scenario, different OS X version is needed, e.g. 10.9, 10.11, etc. Can I install two VM guest for each OS X version on one Apple hardware? This might be possible if we treat them as different software and separated EU, and I right?

Thanks.
Best regards,
Jack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Legalities**

First off: as far as asking legal advise on the Internet: ask a lawyer instead.

To get you started:

The EULA for the different OS X versions is available online at http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/.

Note that it is subtly different for each of the versions, so you need to verify them in detail for every version you are interested in, and for the type of use you intend to make.

For e.g. El Capitan (OS X 10.11)
http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf ,
section 2Biii says:

> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software
>   within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control
>   that is already running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software development; (b)
>   testing during software development; (c) using OS X Server; or (d) personal, noncommercial
>   use.
>   The grant set forth in Section 2B(iii) above does not permit you to use the virtualized copies or
>   instances of the Apple Software in connection with service bureau, time-sharing, terminal sharing
>   or other similar types of services.

Typically, (much) older versions prohibit virtual client usage.

Note that you cannot buy an OS X license anymore at all, the right to use it is tied to owning the hardware.

**Virtualization on a mac**

OS X clients are readily supported in VMware Fusion and Parallels. Both use a host OS running OS X and are popular choices in the Mac world.

The installation of a virtual client OS is typically automated with a wizard and should run smoothly as long as you are on current versions.

**Mac mini**

I own and manage a few Mac minis. This is not very high-end hardware in terms of performance. Essentially it's a cheap machine using "laptop" grade hardware in terms of CPU power and amounts of RAM. It's not suitable to run many copies of OS X on it regardless of the legalities.

Macs do however have the ability to install multiple OSes on them and can be made to chose at boot time which OS it will boot (might be enough for your testing purposes).

I somehow doubt VMWARE ESXi makes much sense on a mac mini, but others might have experience.

Also re-imaging form an OS X server is relatively easy to setup and rather painless to execute. (OS X Server is an app you buy once in the App store).

If you look for powerful hardware, look for a Mac Pro.

Comment: Thanks! I'll forward my question to legalities department. The reason why I'm doing this is trying to setup isolated development and CI environments. Mac Pro might be too much powerful and high cost in this scenario. Newest generation Mac mini do have less power than 2012 model, but still works. Using visualization technology is trying to create isolated environments as much as possible, otherwise, with no limited budget, just buy lots of Mac mini or Mac Pro. :)